# DeclarationError : Only constant variables are allowed at file level

Tags: solidity, remix

i just start learning the solidity and smart contract and i got this error

> ***DeclarationError : Only constant variables are allowed at file level***
> this is my code :

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    
    pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
    
    contract SimpleStorage {
        address Address;
        string name;
    }
    
    struct People {
        string Name;
        address Address;
    
    }
    
    People[]  people;
    
         

 mapping(string => address)  NametoAddress;

          
    
    function addPerson(string memory _Name, address memory _address)  {
        people.push(People(_Name, _address));
        NametoAddress [_Name] = _address;
       

}
```

the error is in this 3 lines :

> People[]  people;
>
> mapping(string => address)  NametoAddress;
>
> function addPerson(string memory _Name, address memory _address)  {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of the wrong placement of the `}`.

```js
contract SimpleStorage {
    address Address;
    string name;
}
```

Because of this, the contract, technically ends after declaring the name string. Everything else is considered to be outside the contract, hence you got the error.

However, there are a couple more issues in the code, unrelated to this error.

1. You need to mention the visibility for `addPerson` function.
2. Input parameter `_address` doesn't need the keyword 'memory' as data location is only required for arrays, mapping and stucts.

```
function addPerson(string memory _Name, address _address) public {
    ...
}
```

The whole contract after the changes will be like this

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
    
contract SimpleStorage {
        
    address Address;
    string name;
    
    struct People {
        string Name;
        address Address;
    }
    
    People[]  people;
    
    mapping(string => address)  NametoAddress;
    
    function addPerson(string memory _Name, address  _address)  public {
        people.push(People(_Name, _address));
        NametoAddress [_Name] = _address;
    }

}
```

All the best with solidity!

Answer (score 0):

Error `DeclarationError : Only constant variables are allowed at file level` comes when a programmer tries to make a non-constant public variable.
you can make public variable to be used in different contract under same smart contract, but it should constant like this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
address constant Address=0xabcd...;
string constant name="name can not be changed";    
contract SimpleStorage {
   ...
}
```

here, as @pbsh also said, your error came because of the wrong `{ }` placement. corrected codes:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT    
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
    
contract SimpleStorage {
    address Address;
    string name;
    
    struct People{
        string Name;
        address Address;
    }
    
    People[] people;
    
    mapping(string => address)  NametoAddress;      
    
    function addPerson(string memory _Name, address _address) public{
        people.push(People(_Name, _address));
        NametoAddress [_Name] = _address;
    }
}
```